# Why isn't the spread operator passing my array by value instead of by reference?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry for the vague title. In the function below:

```
1  function updateArray(data, columns, rows){
2     let returnData = [...data];
3     for(let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
4         for(let j = 0; j < columns; j++){
5             const compareArr = [[i-1, i, i+1], [j-1, j, j+1]];
6             const sum = sumFunction(compareArr, data, columns, rows);
7             if(data[i][j]){
8                 if(sum !== 2 && sum !== 3){
9                     returnData[i][j] = !returnData[i][j]
10                }
11            }
12            else{
13                if(sum === 3){
14                    returnData[i][j] = !returnData[i][j]
15                }
16           }
17        }
18    }
19    return returnData;
20 }
```

Line 9 is mutating `data` (and I suppose line 14 would do the same). I know that line 9 is mutating `data` because I've run this function through the debugger in VSCode and `data[i][j]` is changed after this line is run. I thought that `returnData` would be the only array mutated here. I've tried assigning `data` to `returnData` using other methods, including `returnData = data.slice(0)`, but I get the same result. Am I still assigning `data` to `returnData` by reference? Is there any easy way to pass just the values of `data` to `returnData`? In my test case, `data` is a 3x3 array.

Comment: You are shallow-copying the array, and seem to intend a deep-copy. Long story short, `const a = [{ prop: 'value' }], b = [...a]; console.log(a !== b, a[0] === b[0]);`

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to read up on that and see if I can figure it out from there. @ASDFGerte

Comment: I wish i'd had a good article for this ready, but i don't. `let returnData = [...data]` is copying the array elements (shallow copy) to a new array, but the elements of the array are references to other arrays. When you copy those references to a new array, the new array containing them is different to the original (changing the first layer would not be reflected in `data`), but if you follow a reference, you'll still end up at the same array as referenced from `data`, and changing anything there will then accordingly show up as well, when following the reference in `data`.

Comment: Got it. I figured that was the case. I'm trying to use a reduce function, so `let returnData = data.reduce((acc, elem) =>{acc.push([..elem])}, [])` or something similar to that. Testing that out now.

Comment: Nice. That seemed to work. Thanks again. @ASDFGerte